# Блокировать сворачивание меню при переходе по ссылке в нем

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

При переходе на любой из пунктов меню в сайдбаре оно закрывается, грузится страница, на которую перешли, и меню в сайдбаре снова открывается. Как сделать так, чтобы меню не закрывалось при переходе и тем самым не моргало.

[Мой сайт с проблемой](http://metallcenter.uz/products/armatura_a3)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вешать событие открытия подменю только на верхний уровень, а не на всех потомков. Сейчас у вас так

```
$('.menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('red');
  });
```

попробуйте так

```
$('.menu > li').click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('red');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если решение Александра не поможет.
Можно попробовать остановить бабблинг. 
Под вот этим куском кода

```
$('.menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('red');
  });
```

нужно добавить

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

Полностью блок должен выглядеть вот так:

```
$(function() {
  $('.menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('red');
  });
  $("li a").click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

Comment: Александра не помогло, вставил ваш код, он перестал сворачиваться, но вот новую стр открывает, и сайт бар может быть закрыт, а через секунду откроется без анимации, будто моргание